# Tabs using jquery not working

Tags: jquery, css, tabs

I am trying to create a tab in jQuery, when the tab is clicked nothing happens but the url changes as if the tab has been clicked. Don't know what could be wrong. Any one have any idea as to way this is not working?

```js
$(function() {
 jquery('.tabs .mytabs a').on('click', function(event) {
  var currentAttrValue = jquery(this).attr('href');
    jquery('.mytabs' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();
    jquery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
#tabs {
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
}
/* Clearfix */
.mytabs:after {
  display:block;
  clear:both;
  content:'';
}
.mytabs li {
  margin:0px 5px;
  float:left;
  list-style:none;
}
.mytabs a {
  padding:9px 15px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:3px 3px 0px 0px;
  background:#7FB5DA;
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight:600;
  color:#4c4c4c;
  transition:all linear 0.15s;
}
.mytabs a:hover {
  background:#a7cce5;
  text-decoration:none;
}
li.active a, li.active a:hover {
  background:#fff;
  color:#4c4c4c;
}
.tab-content {
  padding:15px;
  border-radius:3px;
  box-shadow:-1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  background:#fff;
}
.tabs {
  display:none;
}
.tabs.active {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div id="tabs">
   <ul class="mytabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#yoursaved">Your History</a></li>
    <li><a href="#yourdetails">Your Details</a></li>
    <li><a href="#yourcar">Your Car</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div id="tab">
  <div id="yoursaved" class="tab-content">
    <p>tab 1</p>
  </div>
 <div id="yourdetails" class="tabs">
    <p>tab 2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="yourcar" class="tabs">
    <p>tab 3</p> 
  </div>
```

UPDATE

They now display the information when the tab is clicked but when they are clicked the only thing that appears is the words "tab 2" or "tab 3" nothing else appears no even the tabs. So confused, any idea why this is?

SECOND UPDATE

All tab information appears below each other when the page is loaded, any idea why this is?

Comment: I know you have answers, but really your first line of code in the event handler should be `event.preventDefault();` then the rest of your code. That way if there is any runtime error in the rest of your code the navigation will still be cancelled.

Comment: Please don't delete code in the way you have here (in both your question and all the answers), it is considered vandalism.

Answer (score 1):

Here is working example, you can't use keyword `jquery`. It is `jQuery` or `$` sign:

```js
 $(function() {

   jQuery('.mytabs li a').on('click', function(event) {

     var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');


     console.log(currentAttrValue);
     jQuery(currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

     jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');


     event.preventDefault();

   });
 });
```

```css
#tabs {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
/* Clearfix */

.mytabs:after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  content: '';
}
.mytabs li {
  margin: 0px 5px;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}
.mytabs a {
  padding: 9px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
  background: #7FB5DA;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #4c4c4c;
  transition: all linear 0.15s;
}
.mytabs a:hover {
  background: #a7cce5;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li.active a,
li.active a:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #4c4c4c;
}
.tab-content {
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  background: #fff;
}
.tabs {
  display: none;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  background: #fff;
}
.tabs.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs">
  <ul class="mytabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#yoursaved">Your History</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#yourdetails">Your Details</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#yourcar">Your Car</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>

<div id="tab">
  <div id="yoursaved" class="tab-content">
    <p>tab 1</p>
  </div>

  <div id="yourdetails" class="tabs">
    <p>tab 2</p>
  </div>

  <div id="yourcar" class="tabs">
    <p>tab 3</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

console output is just to see what is currentAttrValue

Answer (score 1):

You had a few small things going wrong here but in particular:

```
jQuery('.tabs .mytabs a').on('click', function(event) {
```

tabs is an id not a class so it should be

```
jQuery('#tabs .mytabs a').on('click', function(event) {
```

a working fiddle [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/1ec0dygd/)

Another thing that was an error is this line:

```
jquery('.mytabs' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();
```

The items you trying to show do not exist in .mytabs they exist in #tab which i don't think you even need to use. just try:

```
$(currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();
```

this will work with the id you have saved in the link href attr

EDIT (added from comment):

The reason your tab backgrounds don't display is actually css and html related. Try this instead:

```
<div id="tab">
  <div id="yoursaved" class="tab-content active">
    <p>tab 1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="yourdetails" class="tab-content">
    <p>tab 2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="yourcar" class="tab-content">
    <p>tab 3</p>
  </div>
</div> //this was missing from init code also
```

remove this css:

```
.tabs {
  display: none;
}

.tabs.active {
  display: block;
}
```

and do this:

```
.tab-content {
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  background: #fff;
  display:none;
}

.tab-content.active {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: try changing all your 'jquery' which all should be 'jQuery' anyways to '$' as @ZeevKats suggested

Comment: also change `jquery('.mytabs' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();` to  `$(currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();`

Comment: that was yet another problem and I will add it to my answer but your `$(function() {` was never closed. you closed the click function but not this one. Add another `});` at the end of your js

Comment: that is slightly different issue...i will add it to my answer

Comment: you should have only 2 closing `});` in the js provided

Comment: my mistake...that one must have been a copy and paste error on my end in the beginning of all this :) i added the css issue to my answer now also. I will remove the bit about closing the function

Comment: I'm sorry I tried...its working in this fiddle [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/xanfar/1ec0dygd/2/) unless I'm missing something

Comment: ok...last thing I would say try is using `$( document ).ready(function() {` instead of `$(function() {`

Comment: ok i made a small css change in this fiddle [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/xanfar/1ec0dygd/3/) and I will add it to answer. Hope you get it worked out

Comment: That is also solved in the last part of my answer...add class tab-content to each tab then add class active to the one you want to display. Please see answer for the CSS changes. Also note you were missing the closing </div> on your #tab container

Answer (score 1):

You write `.tab` in your selector and its should be `#tab`.
 Its work fine, take a look:

```js
$(function() {
 $('#tabs .mytabs a').on('click', function(event) {
  var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');
  $(currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();
  $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
#tabs {
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
}
/* Clearfix */
.mytabs:after {
  display:block;
  clear:both;
  content:'';
}
.mytabs li {
  margin:0px 5px;
  float:left;
  list-style:none;
}
.mytabs a {
  padding:9px 15px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:3px 3px 0px 0px;
  background:#7FB5DA;
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight:600;
  color:#4c4c4c;
  transition:all linear 0.15s;
}
.mytabs a:hover {
  background:#a7cce5;
  text-decoration:none;
}
li.active a, li.active a:hover {
  background:#fff;
  color:#4c4c4c;
}
.tab-content {
  padding:15px;
  border-radius:3px;
  box-shadow:-1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  background:#fff;
}
.tabs {
  display:none;
}
.tabs.active {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs">
   <ul class="mytabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#yoursaved">Your History</a></li>
    <li><a href="#yourdetails">Your Details</a></li>
    <li><a href="#yourcar">Your Car</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div id="tab">
  <div id="yoursaved" class="tab-content">
    <p>tab 1</p>
  </div>
 <div id="yourdetails" class="tabs">
    <p>tab 2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="yourcar" class="tabs">
    <p>tab 3</p> 
  </div>
```

**[Fiddle demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/zeevkatz/appcszdj/)**